# How can I submit multiple python files with named arguments?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have some python files to submit.

```
a.py
b.py
c.py
```

The `a.py` is the main file and it parses arguments like this.

```
    argument_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    argument_parser.add_argument('--some-value')
    argument_parser.add_argument('--other-value')
    argument_parser.add_argument('--and-so-on')
```

I think I know how to use `--py-files` option.

```
spark-submit \
  ... \
  --py-files a.py,b.py,c.py
```

And when I put arguments like this.

```
spark-submit \
  ... \
  --py-files a.py,b.py,c.py
  --some-value some \
  --other-value other \
  --and-so-on and
```

I seems those arguments passed to the `spark-submit` and it complains.

```
Error: Unrecognized option: --some-value
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try：

```
spark-submit \
  ... \
  --py-files b.py,c.py \
  a.py \
  --some-value some \
  --other-value other \
  --and-so-on and
```

Comment: Oh.. the order of *.py files?

Comment: ```a.py``` is the entry point of the program and needs to be listed separately.